# How to save 2 data from SQL into 2 different PHP variables?

Tags: php, sql, variables

I'm fetching data from 2 tables with one common column and and the query is returning values as expected. How to save these two values "Normal" and "Normal" gotten from "disease" and "cases" column, into 2 different variables in PHP?

This is my query:

```
SELECT healthdb.disease, criminaldb.cases 
FROM criminaldb NATURAL JOIN healthdb WHERE aadharnos = {$aadharnos};
```

The output was:

[image: Output from SQL stmt]

How to save this text "Normal" in PHP variable `{$case}` and other value, "Normal" in another PHP variable `{$disea}` so that I can compare them within if condition for my next part of my code

Comment: Please show us your code (not just the query) and show us where you're stuck. I'm not really understanding what the actual issue is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [fetch-assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) so you will have all the data return from the SQL query in PHP variable.

Consider the following:

```
$query = "SELECT healthdb.disease, criminaldb.cases FROM criminaldb NATURAL JOIN healthdb WHERE aadharnos = $aadharnos;";
$results = $connectToDb->query($query);
while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()){
    print_r($row);
    //here you can access the row data returned and save your data in local variable 
    $crim = $row["cases"]; 
    $dis = $row["disease"]; 
    if($crim == "Normal" AND $dis == "Normal) {
    // or you can just do: if($row["cases"] == "Normal" AND $row["disease"] == "Normal) {
        //some code
    }


}
```

Comment: I want those two values saved in two different PHP variables and not to  print  that anywhere

Comment: @ShashankVRay - If you first output the `$row`-variable using `print_r()`, you will see that it's just an array with the values, which you can use to get the values you need. Also, no need to store them in new variables since you already have an array that contains the values.

Comment: <?php
            $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "password", "maindb");
            if ($con==false) {
                die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
            } 
            
    $query = "SELECT healthdb.disease, criminaldb.cases FROM criminaldb NATURAL JOIN healthdb WHERE aadharnos = $aadharnos;"
    $results = $con->fetch($query);
    while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()){
    echo print_r($row);
    
    ?>

This was the code that I tried running, but am resulting to see a Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$results' (T_VARIABLE) error

Comment: @ShashankVRay - You're missing the `;` after the SQL string and the closing `}` for your `while`-loop.

Comment: <?php $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "password", "maindb");
if ($con==false) { die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error); } 
      
    $query = "SELECT healthdb.disease, criminaldb.cases FROM criminaldb NATURAL JOIN healthdb WHERE aadharnos = '987654321';";
    $results = $con->fetch($query);
    while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()){
    echo print_r($row); 
}
    
    ?>

This was the code that I tried running, but am resulting to see a Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli::fetch() in C:\xampp\htdocs\maindb\try.php:8 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown

Comment: <?php  $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "password", "maindb");
 if ($con==false) {
 die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
   } 
            
    $query = "SELECT healthdb.disease, criminaldb.cases FROM criminaldb NATURAL JOIN healthdb WHERE aadharnos = '987654321';";
    $results = $con->fetch($query);
    while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()){
    print_r($row);
    //here you can access the row data returned and save your data in local variable 
}
    ?>

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli::fetch() in Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown

Comment: Try `$results = $connectToDb->query($query);`

Comment: Yes, @DavidWinder; your last piece of code worked and am getting the output as
    Array ( [disease] => normal [cases] => normal )

Now how to save them in 2 variables so that I can apply
if($crim == "Normal" AND $dis == "Normal) {
//some code
}

Comment: @ShashankVRay updated my answer with how to use that `if` statement

Comment: You still have left the $results = $connectToDb->fetch($query); line as it is, but in my case, $results = $con->query($query); this line of code worked!
and, may i know why have you used a while loop there?
You've applied while loop even for the if condition
What was that for?

Comment: @ShashankVRay - fixed the query. The while loop is there in case there are more then one result from the DB (that why the `if` statement is in there - she applied for all the result - even if you're expecting to only one).
If my answer helped you please mark it as accepted (the "v" mark at the left of the post so other may use it as well)